# iPhone App crashing in beta/ adhoc test. But works fine on Debug mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-App purchase in my iPhone app and its working fine on debug Mode. But once i do an adhoc test via Testflight/iTunes it crashing at the  purchasing process.

I am using test users credentials to purchase.I have posted my crash log here. Thanks in advance.

http://pastebin.com/C6WZVTtK

Comment: seems like you are accessing a deallocated object, but it is impossible to say what is happening without seeing the code.

Comment: @sergio but how it working on debug mode ? and not working on adhoc test ?